# How to save attributes using Form Objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I have a user model which consists of 8-10 attributes.
I tried to use form object concept to extract out the validations stuffs into another UserForm Class.
FYI I am using Rails 4 :)

My controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create 
    @user = UserForm.new(user_params)
    @user.save
  end

   def user_params
      # Granted permission for all 10 attributes. 
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email....)
    end
end
```

My custom class looks like this:

```
class UserForm < ActiveModel::Validator
  # like this i have 10 attributes 
 attr_accessor  :first_name, :last_name, :email, ....
 #validation for all 10 attributes 


  def save
    if valid?
      persist!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  private
    def persist!
      #I think this is a bad idea, putting all 10 attributes.
      #User.create(first_name: first_name, email: email, .... )
      # what better solution we can have here ? 
    end

end
```

Now everything seems quite good so far. Just I am confused how to get all attributes saved directly with User.create (in persist! method) rather than manually assigning each and every value ?

Answer (score 0):

UserFrom.create(user_params)

Also, why not just User.create(user_params) ?

Comment: "Also, why not just User.create(user_params) ?"
if I do this way then what's the point of having a separate UserForm Class which will abstract out the validation and create,save related stuffs.. 
keeping all the business logic(db related) in model, I am trying to get on the basic validation stuffs in a separate class. 
by the way, UserForm.create(user_params) not gonna work, as UserForm don't have any create method.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into "Virtus" gem. it makes dealing with Form object really easy.
https://github.com/solnic/virtus

```
class UserForm < ActiveModel::Validator

include Virtus.model
 attr_accessor  :user


 attribute :first_name, String
 attribute :last_name, String
 attribute :email, String
 and so on..

  def save
    if valid?
      persist!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  private
    def persist!
       @user = User.create(self.attributes)
    end

end
```